# Ajv validation ignores format "uri"

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsonschema, ajv

I am using **Ajv** to check whether a json object is complying with a json schema, but **Ajv** fails to detect "**uri**" format violations.

I am using the npm package **ajv** (v. 8.12.0) and **ajv-formats** (v.2.1.1) to validate
`myData` against `mySchema`:

```
import Ajv from 'ajv';

const myData = { a: "https://a.=.c" };

const mySchema = {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "a": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "uri"
    }
  }
};

const ajv = new Ajv({ strict: true, allErrors: true, verbose: true });
const addFormats = require("ajv-formats");
addFormats(ajv);

const isValid = ajv.validate(mySchema, myData);
```

`isValid` is `true` but I expected it to be `false`, because some online json schema validators report "uri" format errors, e.g.:

[JsonSchemaValidator](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net): `String 'https://a.=.c' does not validate against format 'uri'.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The ajv behavior is as it should be. The doc on [json-schema.org](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/string.html#built-in-formats)
clearly states, that the **uri** format respects specification [RFC3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986).
The chosen example is complying with that specification.